# Sufficient conditions for a sum over a countable set to be well-defined

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $W$ is a countable set and $f:W\to\mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued function. I would like to know the sufficient conditions so that the concept
$$
\sum_{w\in W}f(w)\tag{$*$}
$$
is well-defined.

Specifically, because $W$ is countable, there is an enumeration of its elements as $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots\}$ so that we may define $\sum_{w\in W}f(w)$ as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(w_n)$. But how do we know when the latter quantity is independent of our particular enumeration?

This is from my independent reading and is related to another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923048/breaking-up-a-countable-sum). I hope you could provide rigorous answers or point me to sources with rigorous answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum
$$
\sum_{w\in W}f(w)
$$
is independent of the choice of enumeration of $W$ precisely if
$$
\sum_{w\in W}|f(w)|=\sup\left\{\sum_{w\in V} |f(w)| : V\subseteq W\ \&\ V\text{ is finite}\right\}<\infty.
$$
This is called **absolute convergence**.

I'm looking at Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3rd edition, pages 75–78.  We have Theorem 3.54, stating that if a series converges but does not converge absolutely, then it can be rearranged (i.e. a different enumeration chosen) to converge to $-\infty$ or $+\infty$ or anything in between, and Theorem 3.55, saying if a series of complex numbers converges absolutely, then all rearrangements converge to the same sum.

There is also [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate or provide a reference so I could go read on it?

Comment: That was a wonderful edit. You are great, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, but theorem 3.55 is not enough to prove the result at hand, since it only considers rearrangements of the same order type as the natural numbers.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : I think if you read the question carefully, you'll see that rearrangements with other order types are not relevant to it.

Comment: I've thought carefully about this, Michael. It is just a matter of formalism.